# JQuery string, how to split and change the order

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, split

I'm wondering is there a way to split a `string` in *JQuery* and display it in different order ?
For example: *aaa bbb, ccc* should be *bbb aaa ccc* (no comma!)

```
<div class="string">aaa bbb, ccc</div>
```

Any ideas welcome

Comment: Using plain JavaScript you can split on non alphabetics `/[^a-z]/` if that is relevant

Comment: jQuery doesn't have its own strings. *JavaScript* does, though.

Comment: true, which is why I removed my comment :)

Comment: Is that always the change? Middle and first one to swap? Also, is there only ever going to be 3 items?

Comment: I don't think reordering can be done automatically. You can use join to remove the , character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends specifically on what you want to achive and there are several ways but this is one way:

```
var text = $('.string').html().replace(',','').split(' ');

$('.string').text(text[1] + ' ' + text[0] + ' ' + text[2]);
```

See it live here: http://jsfiddle.net/Trufa/7DG8G/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can split those. Looks like you'll need both space and comma to be delimiters, so:

```
var str = "one two, three";
var parts = str.split(/[ ,]+/);
```

That gives you an array (`"one", "two", "three"`). You can then reorganize the elements as you like. In this case, looks like you're swapping the first two. When you have the array the way you want it, you can recombine it with `join`:

```
//...update `parts`, then:
str = parts.join(" ");
```

Alternately, if you're always just swapping the first two, and there are always three, you could use `replace` with a regular expression:

```
var str = "one two, three";
str = str.replace(/^([^ ,]+)[ ,]+([^ ,]+)[ ,]+([^ ,]+)(.*)/, "$2 $1 $3$4");
```

`([^ ,]+)` means "capture a series of characters at least one character long that doesn't contain space or `,`". `[ ,]+` means "match a series of spaces and/or commas. In the replacement string, `$1` refers to the first capture group, $2 to the second, etc.

Comment: OP did not ask to reverse, output should be "bbb aaa ccc" (or in your example, "two one three")

Comment: @SmokeyPHP: Yeah, just noticed that thanks to someone's comment on the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The split() method is used to split a string into an array of substrings, and returns the new array and then join as per your wish.

```
 str.split("[,\\s]+");
```